# Split Columns into separate variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have the below code to display db column data as table headings

```
 $reportID=$_GET["reportID"];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reportFields")or die('Could not connect:loggod line 30 iD' . mysql_error());
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);   

  echo "    <tbody> "; // first row beginning
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

   $field = $row ['field'];

   echo "         
        <th>$field</th> 

        ";  }

    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo ''; // it's time no move to next row
    }
```

This works fine, however I am wondering how I get each $field as a separate variable?

Can anyone help?

Also, sorry if this is a vague question, but I am a newbie and probably trying to do something confusing!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$row['field']` refers to the sql column named `field`, so `$row['reportName']` would look at the reportname column. So that's all you need to get the different fields.   If you are talking about storing the different rows, you can read them into an array and go back to reference them.

Comment: It is hard to explain what I mean. $field is stored in the database against the reportID. I need to select all data that has a reportID of 1 but split them into separate variables - does that make sense?

Comment: it is a little confusing as a question, because many people refer to the columns/attributes of a db table as `fields`, so when you use it for rows or fields...it's difficult to discuss.

Comment: ahh, I see.  change your query to `SELECT * FROM reportFields WHERE reportID=1`

Comment: Ok, lets say `field` is called `name` does that make it any easier?

Comment: what are the columns in your db.  I now know that one of them is reportID, what are the others?

Comment: @RightClick - Yep, Ive added `WHERE` into my query. But how do I get each field as a separate variable?

Comment: @RightClick - `reportID` and `field`

Comment: @RightClick - Could we move to chat?

Comment: oh, I just saw it, haha.  You aren't looping through the results

Comment: how do i loop the results? - sorry :/

Comment: you must have taken from 2 examples, right?  hold on a sec, got the answer coming

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for PHP's [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function? It takes an associative array and makes the values local variables, with the names being the key in the array.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Can we move to chat?

Comment: @RightClick - Papa Dragon's answer below is what I needed, any chance you know the answer to my last question on his answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you wrote in the comments...

```
$reportID=$_GET["reportID"];
$query  = "SELECT * FROM reportFields WHERE reportID=$reportID";
$result=mysql_query($query)or die('Could not connect:loggod line 30 iD' . mysql_error());
$i=1;
echo "<tbody><tr>"; // first row beginning
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){  
    $field = $row ['field'];
    $reportID = $row ['reportID'];
    echo "<td>$reportID</td>";  
    echo "<td>$field</td>";  
    if ($i % 4 == 0)echo '</tr><tr>'; // it's time no move to next row
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr></tbody>";
```

Comment: Thanks - See Papa Dragon's answer below, that is exactly what I need however just need to know how many fields there are, see my comments

Answer (score 1):

It is very unclear question. And you have very weird code.

Just my guess about what you are asking for:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reportFields")or die('Could not connect:loggod line 30 iD' . mysql_error());
echo "<table><thead><tr>";
$i=0; 
$fields = array();
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
    $metaField = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    $fields[] = $metaField;
    echo '<th>'.$metaField->name.'</th';
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr></thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
   echo '<tr>';
   foreach( $fields as $field) 
     echo '<td>'. $row [$field->name].'</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but that prints the whole table

Comment: Do you need just a head? so comment the `tbody` part.

Comment: Thanks - See Papa Dragon's answer below, that is exactly what I need however just need to know how many fields there are, see my comments

Comment: imho you just think that you need that. in reality it almost impossible develop the code with unknown variable names. much easier use regular technique to get information. but good luck with your project.

Comment: The answer below works though? I just need to know how many fields there are to echo them as $field1 $field2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the answer you are looking for but you can do this

```
$field = [$row ['field']];
```

Now to echo out all the values

```
foreach($field as $v){
    echo "<th>$v</th>";
}
```

Comment: replace $field = $row ['field']; with ${'field'.$i} = $row ['field']; then to call the variable do $field1, $field2, ...

Comment: If I replace it with your code, will that automatically set $field1, $field2 etc?

Comment: @hello Yes it will automatically set $field1, $field2, ... to how ever many records you have in your db

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, only thing is, how do I know how many fields, for echoing purposes?

Comment: once it is done setting the variables $i will equal number of rows

Comment: Sorry I dont understand - I have added your code and this  `<?php echo"<th>$field1</th> <th>$field2</th><th>$field3</th><th>$field4</th> <th>$field5</th> <th>$field6</th> <th>$field7</th>";?>` however there are only 5 fields (i looked in the DB) is there a way of only echoing the number of fields?

Comment: because you are not playing with fields, you are playing with rows. so you have 7 records in your table

Comment: How do i know how many rows there are? to echo $field1, $field2 upto the number of rows?

Comment: see my edit. I changed it to an array so you can easily loop through the values